# How to create a rpm according a exist one?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I want to create "snapd" rpm on HUAWEI's OS(openEuler OS), but I have no experience with rpmbuild. In snapd's github repository, there are many spec file for other Linux distribution like CentOS. What should I do to install snapd successfully on openEuler? It seems a total go project, may I could first go run main.go to run snapd, cause source code is also in github repository, but i got this problem:

```
[root@myOpenEuler2303 snapd]# go run main.go
2023/08/12 14:34:46.616748 overlord.go:272: Acquiring state lock file
2023/08/12 14:34:46.618640 overlord.go:277: Acquired state lock file
2023/08/12 14:34:46.652502 daemon.go:247: started snapd/unknown (series 16; classic; devmode) openeuler/23.03 (amd64) linux/5.4.119-20.0009.21.spr.
2023/08/12 14:34:46.673454 main.go:129: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount: /tmp/syscheck-mountpoint-1047546609: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
2023/08/12 14:34:46.673504 daemon.go:340: adjusting startup timeout by 30s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
2023/08/12 14:34:46.687999 backends.go:58: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
cannot run daemon: state startup errors: [cannot obtain snap-seccomp version information: fork/exec /usr/lib/snapd/snap-seccomp: no such file or directory]
exit status 1
```

Comment: Why do you need to package it instead of installing it locally? And if you really need a package, why not just use the fedora one?

Comment: openEuler is a Linux distribution develop from fedora, I can not install it directly, so I need build it from source code, the source code is a go project, but it looks go wrong, the log is show up.

Comment: That doesn't answer why you need a custom built package instead of using the ready-made one for Fedora

Comment: sorry, I have no experience with this. openEuler maybe is different with fedora? I just want refer to fedora to install snapd on openEuler. But I when `rpmbuild -bc snapd.spec` using fedora one on openEuler, I got log tell me lack for some dependencies, should I install these dependencies by hand?

Comment: Grab the .rpm and associated dependencies from the fedora repo and try to install it, unless Huawei actually did some real deep modifications and not just surface rebranding, it's likely compatible (make sure to grab the rpms from the matching Fedora version).

Comment: How would creating an rpm assist in your situation? rpms are only required if you would want to later install this application on additional servers. But it seems the application doesn't work for you at all. You're trying to run some `go` code that we don't know where you got it from, if there any dependencies, and not even if that's the application you ask about (`snapd`). You first need to make it work. If it doesn't, ask the relevant question about your failure with the relevant details.

Comment: By the way, when you reply to comments and you want the person you replied to to get notified about it, please add his @username. Click on the "Help" link on the right when you start a comment to see more information about how to do that.